# How do I SELECT the most eaten portion of a food from MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `eaten` with history of foods eaten, like this:

```
id | food | amount
1    1      50
2    1      60
3    1      60
4    1      70
5    2      10
6    2      1
7    2      900
8    2      1
9    2      1
10   3      3
```

I need to SELECT the most common `amount` for each `food`. This is the expected result:

```
food | amount
1      60
2      1
3      3
```

Here is my MySQL query that works, but only for one food:

```
SELECT `food`, `amount`, COUNT(`amount`) as `count`
FROM `eaten`
WHERE `food` = 1
GROUP BY `amount`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

For some reason, when I erase the `WHERE` part, the values returned aren't correct. How can I fix this?

Here's the SQL file to re-create the DB to test it: [eaten.sql](http://www.rimmer.sk/eaten.sql)

Comment: How are the values incorrect?

Comment: Your values are wrong when you remove your `WHERE` because you're not grouping by `food`... just `amount`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select rq.food, rq.amount 
from (select food, amount, count(*) amcount
      from eaten
      group by food, amount) rq
join (select food, max(amcount) maxcount from
      (select food, amount, count(*) amcount
       from eaten
       group by food, amount) sq
      group by food) mq
on rq.food = mq.food and rq.amcount = mq.maxcount
```

### [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aea93/1)

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson: Thanks for the SQLFiddle - I had just done the same at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cb0f/1 !

Comment: +1 Hope you don't mind, but since you beat me to the right answer, I figured might as well not let the fiddle go to waste.

Comment: it still returns duplicate values

Comment: Oh! It returns duplicates if there is not prevailing value (for example 10 values with `amcount` = 1).

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
SELECT
    e.*
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT food
      FROM eaten
    ) AS d
  JOIN
    ( SELECT DISTINCT food, amount
      FROM eaten
    ) AS e
      ON e.amount =
         ( SELECT amount
           FROM eaten AS ee
           WHERE ee.food = d.food
           GROUP BY amount
           ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
               LIMIT 1
         ) ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92d9f/1)**

Answer (score -1):

This should give you the most common amount for each food type.  The subselect will give the total for each food and amount.  In the main loop, the GROUP BY clause will make sure the query only returns one record per food type.  The ORDER BY will cause it to take the most common one.

```
SELECT `food`, `amount`, `count`

FROM

(
    SELECT `food`, `amount`, COUNT(`amount`) as `count`
    FROM `eaten`
    GROUP BY `food`, `amount`
    ORDER BY `food`, `count` DESC
) x

GROUP BY `food`
;
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong... grouping by just `food` will just give an arbitrary value for `amount` and `count`.

Comment: @Michael Fredrickson - No, that's not correct.  The order by clause will assure that the amount with the highest count will be used.

Comment: Actually let me check.  It seems like it should work in theory.  Let me try SQL Fiddle.

Comment: The problem is that the `order by` is applied after the `group by`... so it isn't deterministic.  Basically you'll get a random value from the `group by`, and then `order by` that random value.

Comment: Works now.  Apparently the `ORDER BY` clause needs to be in the subselect.

Comment: [From the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html): "The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. Furthermore, *the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an `ORDER BY` clause.*"

Comment: I guess technically you are correct.  Although I am confident this will return the correct results 100% of the time.  Perhaps I should remove my answer, or possibly add a disclaimer.

Comment: I'm not trying to pick on you... but given that the docs say that the results are indeterminate, how can you be confident that the results will be correct 100% of the time?

Comment: An example where this "trick" breaks: **[GROUP BY trick has been optimized away](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/group-by-trick-has-been-optimized-away/)** You don't want your queries/applications to produce incorrect results when your web hosting provider changes from MySQL to MariaDB (because it upgraded RedHat) or when MySQL 5.x adds such improvements to the optimizer, do you?

Comment: @Michael Fredrickson - I have seen this done many times and the results have always been correct.  Since the subquery is ordered the results are always the same.  But like ypercube mentions, a future version of MySQL could change how this works so you're right it is not a best practice to do it in this way.